# Installing Elastic Search over cassandra on live server

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, elassandra

I need to install elastic search over existing Cassandra database.
I have over 50 customers using the server live now.

There is an option to install elassandra [ Elastic search + Cassandra ]. But my customers are using the database live and in order to install elassandra i will have to uninstall Cassandra.

Is there any solution for this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As the server is running right now, you can update node by node to a elassandra installation with deactivated elastic.

Once all nodes are updated, you restart one by one and activate elastic.

In case you have only one server running, you should rethink your architecture

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise alex.Do you know any online reference to install elastic search only with cassandra running as you said, I'm a newbie to this and I'm unable to find any promising online tutorials

Comment: good place to start are the elassandra docs: https://elassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/